# How to use Skype with Empathy in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, skype, empathy

I want to add my Skype account to Empathy to chat with all my contacts from there. I tried the following to integrate Skype with Empathy on Ubuntu 13.04, using [this tutorial](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Empathy) from Ubuntuusers.

1. `sudo apt-get install pidgin-skype`
2. Restart empathy
3. empathy-accounts

But in `empathy-accounts`, which loads very slow, I don't see Skype to select.

How can I integrate Skype with Empathy on Ubuntu 13.04?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use Empathy, but try this.  Install Skype for Pidgin plugin from the Ubuntu Software Center.  Open Skype and log in, and add your Skype account to Empathy `protocol named ‘bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus’` or Pidgin Accounts --> Skype DBUS .  You will need to allow Empathy/Pidgin access to Skype. <sup>Source:J.Sneddon</sup>

> This protocol plugin allows libpurple to communicate with Skype.
>   Applications using libpurple (Pidgin, Finch, Empathy/Telepathy, etc.)
>   can thus show your Skype contacts alongside those from other
>   protocols, and you can communicate with them using that application
>   instead of the Skype user interface.
>
> This plugin communicates with the Skype application in the background
>   to perform its work, so it's necessary to have Skype installed and
>   running. This product uses the Skype API but is not endorsed,
>   certified or otherwise approved in any way by Skype. <sup>Source:USC</sup>

OR

Skype-Wrapper is a small third-party ‘plugin’ that integrates many of Skype’s features directly into the Ubuntu desktop. This includes support for Ubuntu’s Messaging Menu, notification system and Unity launcher. <sup>Source:J.Sneddon</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype-wrapper python-skype
```

Answer (score 2):

Run [JabberSkype](http://jameslow.com/work/jabberskype/) on your Ubuntu PC and then connect Empathy to localhost with a Jabber account.

Comment: Or possibly on another PC that is running all the time for continence?

Comment: Wow, not the most elegant solution!

Comment: I know it's not ideal.. But it's the closest thing I could find for Empathy. Why not just install Skype to your Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I want to unify my chatter channels, thus using the standard Skype is not the option.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately that's the only thing I could find..

Answer (score 1):

This WILL NOT work without regular Skype client running in your desktop. The haze module just connects with that client, not with the skype server.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about using pidgin-skype, but you also need telepathy-haze. Try running `sudo apt-get install telepathy-haze` and restarting Empathy. That should be able to integrate Skype into Empathy. Also Skype must be running in the background for this to work.

Comment: No, not working.

Comment: Are pidgin-skype and telepathy-haze running?

Comment: Doesn't work for me.