# How to bridge skype and empathy in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: skype, empathy

Can some one help me to bridge between `empathy` and `skype`? I followed every post from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310960/how-to-use-skype-with-empathy-in-13-04) and google. But it's not working. There is no option for skype in `gnome-account`.

I have installed `pidgin-skype` and `telepathy-haze`. Also I am using `skype 4.2`. I revert back from `4.3 to 4.2`. Linux `skype` is a crap. I want to use skype using other messenger UI. I also tried wine but no luck. I found that latest version of skype can't be run in wine.

Finally system info:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
unity 7.2.1
empathy 3.8.6
skype 4.2
```

Comment: Where is [here] ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Skype with Empathy in 13.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310960/how-to-use-skype-with-empathy-in-13-04)

Comment: @bleeves Did you really read my question? I already mentioned this link in question.

Comment: So you do not want to use pidgin either?

Comment: @bleeves My question is clearly referring empathy. New version of pidgin has a problem, You can't send file using drag and drop the file into buddy list.

Comment: when I open Empathy to add a VoIP account (skype) as you instructed via a terminal, the 'Skype (dbus)' profile doesn't show up. Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on Ubuntu 14.04, Empathy uses (F4 key) `gnome-account`, but the tutorial using `empathy-skype` and `skype-manager` says to add your Skype account to the Empathy protocol named ‘bigbrownchunx-skype-dbus’.

My solution is to open a terminal and type: `empathy-accounts`. You will open the screen described in the tutorial; then select `Skype (dBus)` profile.